# Invalid json format using this api when using curl php

Tags: php, json, api, curl

This is my json data

```
$data = array(
"api_key"=>"xxxx",  
"email_details"=> array( "fromname"=>"test",  
"subject"=>"Registration",   
"from"=>"xxx@xxx.com",   
"content"=>"test"), 
"recipients"=>["xxx@gmail.com"]
);
```

generated the json data:

```
$str_data = json_encode($data);
```

it gives following format of json:

```
{"api_key":"xxxx",
"email_details":{"fromname":"test","subject":"Registration","from":"xxx@xxx.com","content":"test"},
"recipients":["xxx@gmail.com"]}
```

it is valid json format
verified from this url
http://jsonlint.com/

from the postman i have tried to run the API:

```
https://api.xxx.com/xxx/json?data={"api_key":"xxxx","email_details":   {"fromname":"xxx","subject":"Registration","from":"xxx@xxx.com","content":"test" },"recipients":["xxx@gmail.com"]}
```

it is given the success message

when i tried to run this api from php code :

```
$url_email="https://api.xxx.com/xxx/json?data=";

$chh = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_URL,$url_email);
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
   'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
   'Content-Length: ' . strlen($str_data))                                                                       
);  
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($chh);
curl_close($chh);
```

i didn't get the o/p
getting the error message :

```
{"message":"ERROR","errorcode": "100" ,"errormessage":"Invalid JSON format used in API Call.Hence failed."}
```

whats wrong here ?

Comment: When you tried with postman, was it a POST or a GET request?

Comment: your API need json format?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is POST method

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be:

```
$url_email="https://api.xxx.com/xxx/json";  // no `data` here
$chh = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_URL, $url_email);
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data=' . $str_data); // `data` moved here
```

Comment: still am getting the error message {"message":"ERROR","errorcode": "100" ,"errormessage":"Invalid JSON format used in API Call.Hence failed."}